# Building JSONArray

Tags: java, json

Well I think in that case a piece of code is better than thousands explanation :

**My code :**

```
ArrayList<String[]> req = new ArrayList<String[]>(DAO.getInstance().dropList(request.getParameter("rname")));
JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
JSONArray m = new JSONArray();
for(String[] s : req){
    try{
        j.put("id",s[0]);
        j.put("name",s[1]);
        m.put(j);
        System.out.println("id and name from DAO : " + s[0] + " " + s[1]);
        System.out.println("JSON object : " + j);
        System.out.println("JSON array : " + m);
    }catch (Exception e){}
}
```

**Console :**

```
id and name from DAO : 1 Bob Sinclar
JSON object : {"id":"1","name":"Bob Sinclar"}
JSON array : [{"id":"1","name":"Bob Sinclar"}]
id and name from DAO : 2 Kurt Cobain
JSON object : {"id":"2","name":"Kurt Cobain"}
JSON array : [{"id":"2","name":"Kurt Cobain"},{"id":"2","name":"Kurt Cobain"}]
id and name from DAO : 3 AAA AAcc
JSON object : {"id":"3","name":"AAA AAcc"}
JSON array : [{"id":"3","name":"AAA AAcc"},{"id":"3","name":"AAA AAcc"},{"id":"3","name":"AAA AAcc"}]
id and name from DAO : 4 Bruce Wayne
JSON object : {"id":"4","name":"Bruce Wayne"}
JSON array : [{"id":"4","name":"Bruce Wayne"},{"id":"4","name":"Bruce Wayne"},{"id":"4","name":"Bruce Wayne"},{"id":"4","name":"Bruce Wayne"}]
id and name from DAO : 5 Tyler Dordon
JSON object : {"id":"5","name":"Tyler Dordon"}
JSON array : [{"id":"5","name":"Tyler Dordon"},{"id":"5","name":"Tyler Dordon"},{"id":"5","name":"Tyler Dordon"},{"id":"5","name":"Tyler Dordon"},{"id":"5","name":"Tyler Dordon"}]
```

As you can see instead of adding a new element its replace all the element by the last entry, like I was adding a pointer to my JSONObject and not its content ...

Any idea guys ?

Comment: You should use Objects instead of String[]...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your `JSONObject` **within** the loop.

```
for(String[] s : req){
    try{
        JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
         ...
```

... otherwise you'll update the reference to the `JSONObject` and add it again to the `JSONArray`, hence adding multiple copies of the same `JSONObject`.

Before the `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` are serialized, they behave like normal Java `Object`s, insofar as changes through methods invoked on the same reference are applied to the same instance.

Hence, upon serialization, you'll get multiple copies of the last updated `JSONObject` in your `JSONArray`.

Comment: Yes ! Good job man !
Can you try to explain why is that ? Because I don't get it...

Comment: @Kermit see my append to the answer.

Comment: oooooh ok ! I see ! Still that's an odd behavior ! But I get it. Thx mate.

Comment: @Kermit you're welcome. I don't see anything odd about it though :S

Comment: No you are absolutely right there is no strange behavior at all, it's just that I'm being stupid here :)
It's been a rough day and my brain isn't working very nicely haha

Comment: @Kermit happens to me all the time too :D